# Split List of objects based on object type

Tags: c#, .net, linq, extension-methods

I have list of objects as below - "Text1", "Text2", new UndefinedInfo("Undfined1"), new UndefinedInfo("Undfined2"), new UndefinedInfo("Undefined3"), "Text3"

I need output as below:

Output 
// List> 
0 – Text1, Text2
1 – Undefined1, Undefined2, Undefined3
2 – Text3

I managed to write below function which is bad but somehow working fine. Is there any way to achieve the same using LINQ extensions - TakeWhile or SkipWhile or using yield. Any help highly appreciated:

```
public static List<List<object>> PartitionByTypes(List<object> values)
{
List<List<object>> partitionedList = new List<List<object>>();

        int j;
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Count; i++)
        {
            j = i;
            List<object> subList = new List<object>();
            Type t = values[j].GetType();
            do
            {
                subList.Add(values[j]);
                j++;
                if (j == values.Count)
                {
                    break;
                }
            } while (values[j].GetType() == t);
            partitionedList.Add(subList);
            i = j - 1;
        }

        return partitionedList;
    }
```

Comment: Try this :  string output = string.Join(",", partitionedList.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray());

Comment: I am filling partitionedList at last. How your solution will work? Can u provide sample inputs and outputs?

Comment: Your output is a CSV string (each array items separated by a comma)  My code is simply enumerating through your list an converting each item to a string and then using a string JOIN method to put a comma between each item..  I guess I should of used values instead of partitionList.

Answer (score 2):

The following will do what you want using `yield`.  So the return will be `IEnumerable<List<object>>` instead.

```
public static IEnumerable<List<object>> PartitionByTypes(List<object> values)
{
    Type prevType = null;
    List<object> cache = new List<object>();
    foreach (var value in values)
    {
        if(prevType != null && value.GetType() != prevType)
        {
            yield return cache;
            cache = new List<object>();
        }

        cache.Add(value);
        prevType = value.GetType();
    }

    if(cache.Count > 0)
        yield return cache;
}
```

Alternatively you could use the following Linq query

```
public static IEnumerable<List<object>> PartitionByTypes(List<object> values)
{
    int count = 0;
    return values.Select((o, i) => new 
        { 
            Object = o, 
            Group = (i == 0 || o.GetType() == values[i - 1].GetType()) ? count : ++count 
        })
        .GroupBy(x => x.Group)
        .Select(g => g.Select(x => x.Object).ToList());
}
```

Comment: This will skip last element of the input list i.e. will return list of 2 lists

Comment: @Abhay  I fixed that with the `if(cache.Count > 0) yield return cache;` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do this with LINQ and TakeWhile, but I doubt that will be any better than plain foreach. For example:

```
public static List<List<object>> LinqPartitionByTypes(List<object> values)
{
    var batches = new List<List<object>>();
    while (true)
    {
         object prev = null;
         var batch = values.Skip(batches.Sum(c => c.Count)).TakeWhile(c => {
              var result = prev == null || prev.GetType() == c.GetType();
              prev = c;
              return result;
         }).ToList();
         if (batch.Count == 0)
              break;
         batches.Add(batch);
     }
     return batches;
}
```

However I'd better do something more simple and clean:

```
public static List<List<object>> PartitionByTypes(List<object> values) {
    var batches = new List<List<object>>();
    object prev = null;
    var batch = new List<object>();
    foreach (var value in values) {
        if (prev != null && prev.GetType() != value.GetType()) {
            batches.Add(batch);
            batch = new List<object>();
        }
        batch.Add(value);
        prev = value;
    }
    if (batch.Count > 0)
        batches.Add(batch);

    return batches;
}
```

Comment: Note that this won't group all instances of the same type in one batch unless somehow the list is sorted by type.

Comment: As I understand that's the whole point - split all sequentially going objects of the same type into separate groups.

Comment: You forgot to `return batches;` in your first method.

Comment: Indeed, it behaves the same as OP's current method. My comment is just a note. :)

Comment: @KhaledNassar ...BTW..who is OP here?..:)

Comment: @Abhay You are.  It stands for Original Poster.

Answer (score 0):

```
static Type GetObjectTypeOrNull(object o)
{
    return o == null ? null : o.GetType();
}

static IEnumerable<List<object>> PartitionByTypes(List<object> values)
{
    if (values == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("values");
    if (values.Count == 0) yield break;

    Type currentType = GetObjectTypeOrNull(values);
    List<object> buffer = new List<object>();
    foreach (object value in values)
    {
        Type valueType = GetObjectTypeOrNull(value);
        if (valueType != currentType)
        {
            currentType = valueType;
            yield return buffer;
            buffer = new List<object>();
        }

        currentType = valueType;
        buffer.Add(value);
    }

    if (buffer.Count > 0)
    {
        yield return buffer;
    }
}
```

**Example:**

```
List<object> input = new List<object> { "Text1", "Text2", new UndefinedInfo("Undefined1"), new UndefinedInfo("Undefined2"), new UndefinedInfo("Undefined3"), "Text3" };
PartitionByTypes(input).ToList();
```

Result:

```
{ List<object>(2) { "Text1", "Text2" }, List<object>(3) { [Undefined1], [Undefined2], [Undefined3] }, List<object>(1) { "Text3" }
```

**Another example - with nulls:**

```
List<object> input = new List<object> { null, "Text1", "Text2", null, null, new UndefinedInfo("Undefined1"), null, null, new UndefinedInfo("Undefined2"), new UndefinedInfo("Undefined3"), "Text3" };
PartitionByTypes(input).ToList();
```

Result:

```
List<object>(1) { null }, List<object>(2) { "Text1", "Text2" }, List<object>(2) { null, null }, List<object>(1) { [Undefined1] }, List<object>(2) { null, null }, List<object>(2) { [Undefined2], [Undefined3] }, List<object>(1) { "Text3" }
```

Comment: Thanks @alex.b for null example